# Converting type numeric value from string to integer without changing its value

Tags: php

I am reading a csv file and my code is reading the numeric value as a string.
But i need the value as integer.

e.g.   string `'5782492380'` as int `'5782492380'`

Is there any best way to change the type of value from string to int in php code?

I have tried as

```
(int) 5782492380
```

but it is changing the original value to `2147483647`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with float, as int has a limit under your value:

```
  $v = (float) 5782492380;
```

In [PHP: integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) you can find the comment:

*The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18*

So the integer range value is (-2147483648, 2147483647).

Comment: thanks fedorqui but i have store it into an int field in mysql database

Comment: Checking this page [MySQL Data Types](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-data-types-50.file) I guess you can use `BIGINT` on MySQL side.

Answer (score 2):

Value `5782492380` does not fit into integer type.  Integer values should be in range -2147483648 .. 2147483647 inclusive.  To store values that are outside this range, you may use floating point numbers or [GMP numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php).

Comment: Thanks Mikhail , is there any option to save that value in mysql database as int type

Comment: @Dinesh Sure!  Just define table column as `BIGINT` instead of `INT`.  See the following link for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$v = intval( $your_string)
```

range is up to 2<sup>32</sup>